# solidity run error

Tags: solidity

when i compile a simple code ,i catch with “Expected identifier but got '('
     require(function());” the function how to modify it ? the following is the full code .

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
    contract SimpleAuction {

      address public beneficiary;
      uint public auctionStart;
      uint public biddingTime;


      address public highestBidder;

      uint public highestBid;


      bool ended;


      event HighestBidIncreased(address bidder, uint amount);

      event AuctionEnded(address winner, uint amount);


      function SimpleAuction (uint _biddingTime, address _beneficiary) {
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        auctionStart = now;
        biddingTime = _biddingTime;
      }


      function bid()   {

        require(now > auctionStart + biddingTime) ;


        require(msg.value <= highestBid);



        if (highestBidder != 0) {
          highestBidder.send(highestBid);
        }
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        highestBid = msg.value;
        HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value);
      }


      function auctionEnd() {
        require (now <= auctionStart + biddingTime);
        require (ended);
        AuctionEnded(highestBidder, highestBid);

        beneficiary.send(this.balance);
        ended = true;
      }


         require(function());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your class you have some stray code

```
 require(function());
```

Remove it